# Query to Delete Posts Older than X Days in WordPress

Tags: sql, wordpress, mysql

I run a blog where the community can post time-sensitive community links (sports scores and such). After a certain time, those posts are no longer useful, so I want to delete them in batch via a MySQL query, but I don't know how. I imagine that getting rid of those posts entirely is more than just deleting from the wp_posts table, right? There other tables at work per post, aren't there?

I've tried a couple of auto- or batch-delete plugins, but they don't work half the time.

Please, could you provide a MySQL query to delete posts and their pieces older than X days from all relevant tables?

Thank you in advance.

--Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need MySQL Queries to delete WordPress Posts and Post Meta more than X Days Old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158465/need-mysql-queries-to-delete-wordpress-posts-and-post-meta-more-than-x-days-old)

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress has published its database structure in its Codex.  [Find out more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description).

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, and somewhat less relevant given the introduction of WP-CLI, but I thought I'd answer it in case others wind up here.

> I imagine that getting rid of those posts entirely is more than just deleting from the wp_posts table, right?

That's correct. You'll also want to consider data in the `wp_term_relationships`, `wp_postmeta`, and `wp_term_taxonomy` tables.

Additionally, it's possible a site has older data where WordPress might be using the same `object_id` in the `wp_term_relationships` table for both a post and a link. If it does, things can break in unexpected ways.

That said, WP-CLI commands consider data in the relevant tables and handle the cleanup for you. So, a safer approach is using a SQL query to get a list of post IDs that you want to delete. Then, run the deletion using WP-CLI.

Regarding,

> posts and their pieces older than X days

Instead of defining a set number of days, which can be tricky with SQL, you could specify a specific date and delete posts older than that date.

So, with the SQL/WP-CLI approach, that might look like,

**SQL query**

```
SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'some_optional_type' AND post_date_gmt < 'yyyy-mm-dd';
```

**WP-CLI**

```
wp post delete 123 456 789
```

Also, adding `--defer-term-counting` to the WP-CLI command will improve the performance of batch deletions.

If there's a reason the deletions have to be handled via SQL query, this should do the trick (posts older than 2022 in the example), but I'd highly recommend backing up your database first.

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( b.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'some_optional_type'
AND a.post_date_gmt < '2022-01-01'
;
```

You could review the affected rows (or just the post IDs) before deleting them with a `SELECT *` (or `SELECT ID`) statement in place of `DELETE`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( b.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'some_optional_type'
AND a.post_date_gmt < '2022-01-01'
;
```

To ensure the "old data" possibility isn't relevant to your site, you could first try the same `SELECT`/`DELETE` logic with the relevant statement and this SQL query.

```
DELETE a,b,c
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( b.term_taxonomy_id = d.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE a.post_type = 'some_optional_type'
AND a.post_date_gmt < '2022-01-01'
AND d.taxonomy != 'link_category'
;
```

If you get `Empty set` the old data edge case is unlikely relevant.