# Wordpress: automatically delete posts that are x days old?

Tags: sql, wordpress

For a long time, I have searched for a plugin that will delete posts that are over a certain 'age' (eg. 30 days old). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to have this as something that happens inside Wordpress, or would you be equally happy with a cronjob?

Comment: it's good...in any case :-) or rather, i think it should be already implemented into wordpress and i don't understand why the trash subject is not really considered by developers. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some SQL that will find every post that has been around for 30 days or more:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 30
```

To delete all the posts, you can replace `SELECT * FROM` with `DELETE FROM` — but make sure you take a backup before you do this!

You can then just `cron` that however you like, be that a shell script, a PHP script, or whatever you're most comfortable with.

Comment: thank you very much, how to integrate this into a plugin calling wp cron once a day?

Comment: It can exist entirely outside of Wordpress if you want to keep it simple, just write some PHP that connects to your database and runs the query. There are plenty of good MySQL/PHP tutorials out there.

Comment: If it's solved, don't forget to mark the best answer - it's the green tick on the left hand side.

Comment: Hi Sam, if this answer solved your problem you should hit the "checkmark" next to it :)

Comment: @themerlinproject Don't worry, I'm well-versed in SO - just mentioned the same thing to the OP :)

Comment: $data->query("DELETE * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_type` = 'post' AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 59");
// disconnect
$data->disconnetti();

Comment: "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax..."

Comment: ops... sorry is DELETE FROM... and not DELETE * FROM... my mistake. Regards. i marked. bye

Answer (score 4):

```
delete a,b,c,d
FROM wp_posts a
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships b ON ( a.ID = b.object_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta c ON ( a.ID = c.post_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy d ON ( d.term_taxonomy_id = b.term_taxonomy_id )
LEFT JOIN wp_terms e ON ( e.term_id = d.term_id )
WHERE e.term_id =<category id>
AND a.post_type = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), a.post_date) > 30
```

[Reference](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2010/06/how-to-effectively-bulk-delete-many-posts-in-wordpress.html)

Answer (score 0):

Delete 30 days old post command is :

```
delete FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'post'
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `post_date`) > 30
```

Comment: Could you please specify how your answer differs from @Sam answer?