# how to trash wordpress custom posts automatically based on custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to put agenda items (custom posts) to the trash automatically when the event date is more then a week ago. This function (in functions.php) seems to work partly, put sometimes also trashes newer events. And it creates problems when publishing a new event, because it's already in the trash before it can get published.

```
    function trash_old_events(){

    global $wpdb;

    $lastweek = strtotime( "-7 days" );
    $lastweek = date( "Ymd", $lastweek );

    $query = "
        SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts
        WHERE post_type = 'agenda' OR post_type = 'members_agenda'
        AND post_status = 'publish'
    ";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    if(count($results)){
            foreach($results as $post){

                $startdate = get_field('agenda_date', $post->ID);
                $startdate = strtotime( $startdate );
                $startdate = date( "Ymd", $startdate );

                if ( $startdate < $lastweek ) {
                    wp_trash_post($post->ID);
                }
            }
        }
}
trash_old_events();
```

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317599/wordpress-automatically-delete-posts-that-are-x-days-old

Comment: I saw that post but it didn't help me. Should I do a JOIN in the sql query to get the custom field? Or can I do this in a non sql way?

Comment: Read it: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152786/posts-to-expire-deleted-after-a-date